# Import fixed-width text file into sqlite

Tags: sqlite, text, fixed-width

What is a good way to import fixed-width text files into sqlite tables, preferably without using peripheral software?

E.g. specifying the width of each field

```
Field 1: 10 characters starting with the second character
Field 2: 5  characters starting with the twelfth character
Field 3: 7  characters starting with the eighteenth character
```

The line

```
AABCDEFGHIJABCDEAABCDEFGA
```

would be imported as:

```
Field 1     Field 2  Field 3
ABCDEFGHIJ  ABCDE    ABCDEFG
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sqlite3` tools imports only CSV files.

There are third-party tools that can import fixed-width files, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608838/import-fixed-width-text-to-sql#9609763) shows how to do this inside SQLite with string functions.

Answer (score 9):

The link in the answer above is for generic SQL. Here is one way to do it in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE fixed_width_table (full_string CHAR);
.import fixed_width_file.txt fixed_width_table

CREATE TABLE tmp AS
Select
    SUBSTR(full_string,1,11) AS field1
    ,SUBSTR(full_string,2,5) AS field2
    ,SUBSTR(full_string,2,7) AS field3
FROM fixed_width_table
```

Comment: Thanks! This saved me a lot of time. Just for completeness if anyone is trying to import a fixed-width text file with a variable length last column, then just omit the 3rd parameter in the corresponding `SUBSTR` (e.g. `,SUBSTR(full_string, 10) AS variable_length_last_column`. That will return all of the remaining text on that line.

Answer (score 0):

To import a text file with a fixed length

1. Import the whole file in a table `TestImport` with 1 column [extract](/questions/tagged/extract) (see [import from file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76037061/819887))
2. Write the sql statements you need to query or [data-transform](/questions/tagged/data-transform) the data
3. Do additional work for all [etl](/questions/tagged/etl) needs.

Step 1: Import from your text-file and save it to a db-file.

```
sqlite> .import C:/yourFolder/text_flat.txt TestImport
sqlite> .save C:/yourFolder/text_flat_out.db
```

And now you can do all sorts of [etl](/questions/tagged/etl) with it (step 2 and 3).

Comment: To import a csv file see [sqlite cli import files as csv or other formats](https://sqlite.com/cli.html#importing_files_as_csv_or_other_formats)

Comment: I did run into trouble importing the file. The cause was that every line did contain the Replacement Character `�`. The file was exported from excel. My quess is that it was a `€`-sign that caused the `�` in the text file.