# Why is this TEXT imported as a BLOB to sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I am importing from a tab separated text file to sqlite3.  In most cases, values import as TEXT, however occasionally a value will import as a BLOB.  This usually happens when there is a slightly unusual symbol in the text, such as the | (pipe) symbol.

Why is this happening, and what can I do about it?

I am setting the sqlite `.mode` to `tabs`, and there is no additional information on the encoding of the text file.

Edit: Here's the code:

```
.open filename.sq3
.mode tabs
.import filename.tab tablename
```

Comment: What is the encoding used in your TSV file? How are you importing the TSV file into Sqlite? Please show us your actual code.

Comment: Dai, per the OP, there is no additional information on the encoding.  Also, see code example

Comment: The file *should* be encoded in UTF-8 to use with `.import`. The code uses `sqlite3_bind_text()` to bind values to parameters in an insert statement.

Comment: Does the table already exist before the import? If so, what is its definition?

Comment: @KimPrince "there is no additional information on the encoding" - that's not true. You **can** tell us what character encoding is being used by the TSV files (Is it strict 7-bit ASCII? UTF-8? UTF-16? ISO 8859-1?) Are you sure it's an actual TSV file using `0x09` tab characters? Are string values enquoted? Do the columns of the TSV file match the destination table?

Answer (score 0):

I did run into the same problem. I can not answer `Why is this TEXT imported as a BLOB` but how i was able to fix it. In my case rows that did contain special characters like `ä,ü,ö` were imported as blob.

From the sqlite command prompt the commands are read from `import_from_file.txt`

```
sqlite> .read 'C:\data\rawtext\import_from_file.txt'
```

The file `import_from_file.txt` looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE "Extract" ("extract"   TEXT);
.mode ascii
.separator "@" "\n"
.import C:\\data\\rawtext\\rawdata.txt
```

According to [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) the file `rawdata.txt` is encoded in `ANSI`. With [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) the file was converted to `utf8`. After the file was converted to an UTF8 encoding the sqlite import worked without any blob rows. Every special character like `ä,ü,ö` was readable inside sqlite