# Read, Parse, and Write Text File to Database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, file, text

I have a .txt file that has 3 different sections, a header line, multiple rows of data, and a trailer line.  The header line is a series of characters that are bunched together and are decoded by start position and length:

```
GBGSELLERRTCBM0011120201016
```

(Parsed)

```
GBG|SELLER|RTC|BM|00111|20201016
```

The data section is parsed roughly the same way but has different data and there are numerous lines of this:

```
800374000        272      BAXTER                    939330106MILLSJACKH2020100100000000985356100000000000020190000000086474517         F 701072664259000000000184308890812B1                    042N
```

(Parsed)

```
8|0037400|0        |272      |BAXTER                    |939330106|MILLSTREYH|20201001|000000009853561|0|000000000002019|00000|00086474517         |F| 7|010|726642590|000000001|843088908|1|2B1            |        0|42N|
|
```

The trailer record follows the same type of pattern.

I need to read the text file.  Parse the first line (probably by using substring) and write that to a sql database.  Read through the next (numerous) lines, parse them, then write to database, then read the footer and write to database.  Anyone know of a relatively efficient way to do this?  VB code examples are a big help but can understand C# as well.

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608838 ?

Comment: I have not, but I will review it.  Thank you for the "heads up!"

Answer (score 0):

in this case you need to use multi-mode and you should identify on mode before start parse, you also need to multi parser for each case you can choose parser deppend on mode.

Comment: Would you share some examples of how to do this?  I am not familiar with multi-mode or multi-parsing at all.